# Bonus points (specifically) and how to get them

Tags: team-fortress-2

Is there a comprehensive list of ways to earn bonus points in TF2?  I have seen here and there one way to do it with this class or the other, but there seems to be no complete list that I've found.

[image]

Is there just one way per class?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "bonus points"?

Comment: In your TAB HUD during gameplay, the final score category listing, reading from left to right and starting with kills, deaths, assists.  I believe it's right under the backstab tally.

Comment: Okay, that's what I was thinking. Yeah, the wiki doesn't have a list of bonus point scoring actions so we'll need to make our own. For _science._

Comment: I seem to get the most bonus points when I play pyro. Must be all the extinguishes? I tend to get a couple playing jarate sniper too.

Comment: http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Points

Comment: @badp The wiki does have a list of bonus point actions now.

Comment: @fireDude67 That's because I added it after doing/seeing research for this question.

Comment: @Toomai you deserve a wiki cap!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After in game testing:

- Any **extinguishing** of a teammate by non-Medic action:  via Jarate, Mad Milk, Dispenser, or air blast.
- **Destroying sappers** using the Homewrecker as Pyro
- **Destroying sappers** on friendly buildings **other than your own** as Engineer
- **Killing a Medic** actively healing an opposing player as Scout
- **Stunning** a player with Sandman is 1 bonus point. Moon-shot stuns (long distance) are worth 2 bonus points.
- Healing teammates with **tossed Sandvich/edible**. This is the act of them picking it up, you do not receive healing points.
- 2 Headshots with the **Huntsman** grants 1 bonus point as sniper.

If you have damage indication turned on (*Advanced → Show damage as a number over players*) you will know you gained a bonus point when a purple "+1" (or "+2") appears on the player or teammate that let you gain it.

All other points go towards their respective categories. Cart pushes are added to capture point totals. All backstab and headshot bonuses go to kills.  All direct or indirect healing goes towards healing @ 1 per 600HP healed.

With the rate Valve adds user content to the game, I am unsure if any of the newer weapons grant bonus points upon successful use, but it appears that bonus points are essentially granted for selfless team-centric acts.

Comment: You're missing one that I know of: Huntsman headshots give 0.5 bonus points, in addition to the 1 point per kill and 0.5 points per headshot.

Comment: I believe those bonuses are added directly to the kill count.  I don't think they contribute to the designated "Bonus Points" column.  Have you confirmed this?

Comment: I have confirmed this. One Huntsman headshot results in a total of 1 point: 1 kill, 0.5 headshots, 0.5 bonus. A second arrow in the head bumps your score to 4 points: 2 kills, 1 headshot, 1 bonus.

Comment: One of the rounds that led me to ask this question was that I was honing my spy skills on DeGroot Keep.  I had something like 11 bonus and really had no idea why.  Loadout: knife (the plain, butterfly one) and cloak and dagger.

Comment: What was your pistol?

Comment: Ambassador, but DeGroot is a melee-only map.

Comment: @tiddy:  I *so* want to accept your answer, but I take issue with `Soldiers, Demos, Medics, and Spies don't receive bonus points.`
I play soldier and spy 96.4% of the time and have definitely seen bonus points accumulate as those classes.

Comment: The one thing I have read but have been unable to test is whether killing a fully charged Medic grants a bonus.  This seems to make the most sense to me considering your situation. I have confirmed backstabs do not contribute.

Comment: I main defensive Pyro, and often 25% to 50% of my total score comes from bonus points (anywhere between 20 and [**upwards of 120** at the end of a match](http://cloud.steampowered.com/ugc/596943197177867938/9B8458B1CC934550E75D6BC05541ECC64FF5330A/)). Extinguishing teammates and unsapping buildings is pretty much my day job and I love it. I help my teammates, and I get credit for it — a win-win situation indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Bonus points in my experience tend to be points awarded for doing things that generally aren't considered to be related to the goal (capping the points, killing the enemy). My memory tells me that bonus points apply:

Pyro:
Extinguish a teammate

Possibly air blasting an enemy off the map or into a hazard like a saw

Engineer:
Extinguish a teammate with your dispenser

Sniper:
Extinguish a teammate with jarate

Scout:
Extinguish a teammate with mad milk

Comment: I thought airblasting someone into a hazard just gave you a kill

Comment: Headshots and backstabs have a separate, non-bonus counter.